# redimensionamento de imagem proporcionalmente

Tags: php, jquery

qual é o nome da tecnica utilizada para fazer um redimensionamento de `img` proporcional. por exemplo eu tenho uma imagem de 200x400 e quero mostrar ela em um quadrado 150x150 como faço para redimensionar essa imagem mantendo a proporção?

como gostaria que ficasse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Responsivo?!?!?!

Comment: sim, por exemplo ele vai redimensionar a `img` conforme o tamanho pedido 150x150 e o que sobrar desses 150x150 ela vai ficar com o fundo preto

Comment: Você pode verificar se ela é portrait ou landscape e assim escolher se vai redimensionar pela largura ou altura e centralizá-la. Se ela for mais vertical vai ficar com as tarjas nas laterais e se for mais horizontal elas vão ficar no topo e na base

Comment: tem algum tutorial explicando certinho como fazer isso. nao tenho a menor ideia de como faço isso verificar se a img e mais vertical ou horizontal

Comment: vou editar a resposta com a foto de como gostaria que ficasse

Comment: @srBubbles se você quiser redirecionar com PHP, tem essa biblioteca que pode auxilia-lo. https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize . Assim você terá uma imagem no tamanho correto e o cliente não precisará baixar uma imagem grande para ser redirecionada para um tamanho bem menor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso apenas com CSS usando `max-width` e `max-height`. Para centralizar a imagem eu usei `flex`.

Veja dois exemplos com imagens em diferentes proporções:

```css
.teste, .teste2{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: #ddd;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.teste img, .teste2 img{
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Imagem de 200x400:
<br>
<div class="teste">
   <img src="http://www.narutopedia.ru/w/images/d/de/Unkai2Anime.jpg" />
</div>
<br>
Imagem de 630x354:
<br>
<div class="teste2">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" />
</div>
```